# Modifying the formal grammar of first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, formal-languages, formal-grammar

As it is usually stated, "if $f$ is an $n$-ary function and $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are terms, then $f(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is a term" and "if $R$ is an $n$-ary relation and $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are terms, then $R(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is a formula."

This conception of functions and relations seems counterproductive since 1) it means that every signature needs its own formal grammar and 2) "the language of first-order logic," rather than being *a* language, is actually language family. To circumvent this, I thought to find an alternative grammar which allows formulas and relations to be expressed *without* assigning arity (thus avoiding the need to specify production rules for functions and relations individually). This is my attempt:

```
<formula> ::= ¬ ( <formula> )
        | <quantifier> <variable> . <formula>
        | ( <formula> <connective> <formula> )
        | <relation> ( <csl> )

<term> ::= <constant>
        | <variable>
        | <function> ( <csl> )

<csl> ::= <term> | <csl> , <csl>

<quantifier> ::= ∃ | ∀

<constant> ::= c | <constant>*

<variable> ::= v | <variable>*

<function> ::= f | <function>*

<relation> ::= R | <relation>*
```

Note: connectives are not listed because each functionally complete set of connectives requires a different grammar.

The basic premise is that every theory has a [countably] infinite set of function, relation, and constant symbols but that only *some* of these (specifically those present in the axioms) are *meaningful*. For example, if we have $\forall v.\exists v^*.R^*(v,v^*)$ as an axiom, we can reasonably assert that $R^*$ is a "binary" relation. While $R^*(v,v^*,v^{**})$ is still a *formula*, our theory says nothing about how it ought to be evaluated.

A consequence of this is that every first-order theory ends up being incomplete, since the production rules necessarily result in statements independent of the axioms (of which, the previous is an example). I don't see this as a problem, though, because 1) any sufficiently interesting theory will contain statements neither proven nor disproven by that theory and 2) the definition of "completeness" can easily be adjusted to recapture the classical notion.

Aside from this, are there any major problems with the proposed grammar for first-order logic? Have any other attempts to "unify" first-order logic been made?

Comment: "1) it means that every signature needs its own formal grammar and 2) "the language of first-order logic," rather than being a language, is actually language family." I view these as positive features of first-order logic, not issues to be circumvented.

Comment: "1) any sufficiently interesting theory will contain statements neither proven nor disproven by that theory." I heartily disagree: for example the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ is a very interesting theory.

Comment: But these are the points of view of a model theorist - I am not interested in logic purely for the purposes of foundations of mathematics.

Comment: By putting a bound on the number of symbols in the language, you've ruled out structures involving larger languages. $\aleph_0$-many symbols might seem like enough at first, but there are situations where we want more (e.g. in nonstandard analysis, we form a hyperreal field by taking an appropriate ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$ *enriched by all functions and relations*). As to the arity issue, there's no problem doing what you're talking about but there's no real benefit either that I see (we can translate back to the usual context straightforwardly).

Comment: @AlexKruckman This was meant in reference to Goedel's [first] incompleteness theorem, the "sufficiently interesting" remark was meant jokingly (as a play on "sufficiently strong [to express PA]"). My point was that incompleteness itself is not detrimental, since it's pretty much ubiquitous outside of the relatively "small" set of complete theories (e.g. algebraically closed fields, as you mentioned).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was under the impression that formal languages were, in general, countable by definition. Every book I have read requires that a formal grammar be over a *finite* alphabet, the Kleene closure of which will always be countable. Since the language is a subset of the Kleene closure, it stands to reason that every formal language is countable no?

Comment: @R.Burton "Formal languages" (or grammars) in the context of computer science are quite different from arbitrary first-order languages, which are indeed allowed to be arbitrarily large. See the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2490770/28111).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I wasn't thinking about computer science, I was thinking about what can actually be done within a finite amount of time given a sufficient length of graphite and paper. A language with uncountably many primitive symbols is a language that no human (or machine, for that matter) can make use of. At best, there will be a countable subset of the alphabet from which all statements (spoken or written) are derived.

Comment: @R.Burton That's a rather narrow viewpoint - just because we can't reason within it in our physical reality doesn't mean it's not valuable as an object of study (e.g. see above my comment about nonstandard analysis). And to be honest, restricting attention to only "physically realizable mathematics" is an odd thing to do anyways; you lose a lot of cool stuff when you do that, and I've never understood what's to be gained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103681/discussion-between-r-burton-and-noah-schweber).